# Enterprise Architect - The method SQLQuery of the repository object doesn't work like a native SQL query

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I am using the enterprise architect via the API of SPARX in C#. In the [repository](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/automation/repository3.html) class exists a method called "SQLQuery". I call the method with the following SQL parameter

```
select obj1.name
from t_object obj1 
where obj1.stereotype = 'XYZ'
and obj1.name LIKE '___1%';
```

This sql query works fine via the sql developer (I get the correct result.) but it doesn't work correctly via the API. The result via API is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EADATA version="1.0" exporter="Enterprise Architect">
</EADATA>
```

Is it a bug or is the sql query maybe not correct?

With kind regards
MK

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem:
In case of a DB connection we have to use "LIKE '___1>>>*****<<<'" instead of "LIKE '___1%'

Comment: '*' is the wildcard character for Access database (i.e EAP file) and '%' is the wildcard character for all other DBMS supported by EA. In some contexts you can put in '#WC#' and EA will substitute the appropriate wildcard character for the database you are using. I don't know off the top of my head if it would work with SQLQuery().

Answer (score 0):

`Repository.SqlQuery()` returns the result (record set) as an XML-formatted string. In a C# setting the simplest way of dealing with the result is to load it into an `XmlDocument` and then retrieve the records using `XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName(<column_name>)` and `XmlElement.InnerText`.

The result you posted is an empty result, in other words there are no matches in the database.